# WebScraper C# + htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

i started develop application. Me need take some informations from website after download it in database, and after I need treatment this informations. 
Well, I don't have enough experience and be grateful any of your recomendation.
for example - I'll work with sport site. (https://terrikon.com/football/spain/championship/) 
I need receive informations from table and download this data in DB. 
I tried some ways download data and understand that best way - use "htmlagilitypack".
I read documentation about work with this library and best that i did:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Parser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var html = @"https://terrikon.com/football/spain/championship/";

            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

            var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);

            var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title");

            var table = htmlDoc.QuerySelector("#champs-table > table");

            var tableRows = table.QuerySelectorAll("tr");

            foreach (var row in tableRows)
            {
                var team = row.QuerySelector(".team"); 
                var win = row.QuerySelector(".win");
                var draw = row.QuerySelector(".draw");
                var lose = row.QuerySelector(".lose");
                Console.WriteLine(team.OuterHtml );
            };

        }
    }
}
```

I can receive title of website or all informations, if I'll change this string

```
 var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head");
```

Could you give me advice how can I get informations only from table?
thanks for tour attention
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to also install a Css selector extension for `HtmlAgilityPack` which can be found here:

https://github.com/hcesar/HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelector

With that you can Query your nodes with css selectors.
To get the information from that table you will have to know the CSS selector for it.
In this case its:

`#champs-table > table`

So to get whole table you could do it like this:

```
var table = htmlDoc.QuerySelector("#champs-table > table");
// then query rows of that table:

var tableRows = table.QuerySelectorAll("tr");

// Now each element it tableRows is a <tr> from that html table
// you could access every value in a for each loop
foreach(var row in tableRows)
{
  var team = row.QuerySelector(".team"); // "team" is a css class applied to <td> containing the team name
  var win = row.QuerySelector(".win");
  var draw = row.QuerySelector(".draw");
var lose = row.QuerySelector(".lose");

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I read about CSS selector, good link!
I understand what did you do, but when I tried implement this code I have error in line " var table = doc.QuerySelector("#champs-table > table");"
doc - doesn't exist in the current context. What does it mean?

Comment: your `doc` is called `htmlDoc`, just adjust the variable name. I updated my snippet

Comment: Hm, I tried do it. If I do this exchange I have next problem :"'HTMLDocument' doesn't contain a definition for 'QuerySelector' and no accessible extension method 'QuerySelector' accepting a first argument of type ' HTMLDocument' could be found"

Correctly understand that I can work in this library with 2 technology:1)CSS selector 2)XPATH 
and for both technology I dont need install special packages (NUGET)?

Comment: `QuerySelector` is a extension method from the package that I linked, you will have to install it in your project and import the namespace in order for it to work

Comment: Sorry, one question more. 
I don't have problem with download data, but what do I wrong when I print data from my table?
I attach screen photo with result and command to print. What did I wrong?

Comment: the `OuterHtml` is corretly displayed. If you need the data from that table, you will have to loop through all of the rows as it is in my example, and then Query for some selector with certain data. So for example I mentioned `var team = row.QuerySelector(".team");` - this will get the HTML element with team name

Comment: Yes, I tried do it in the cycle 
My result was - "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode" - 20 times
Could you see my code at the top, I change It

Comment: So the `HtmlNode` is a class from `HtmlAgilityPack`, its the same type as your `table` was, You could also access the `OuterHtml` property from it like you did before

Comment: Something like this:
 Console.WriteLine(Team + node.OuterHtml, win + node.OuterHtml, draw + node.OuterHtml, lose+ node.OuterHtml);
But then I have" HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode<title> ????? etc" questions marks instead of data

Comment: no,no, your `win` is a `node`. so more like `Console.WriteLine(win.OuterHtml);`

Comment: It was first that I tried :) But if I do it, I have exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
win = null

Comment: maybe the `.win` selector that i provided is wrong, check the HTML for that page and put it as the selector

Comment: I checked it, you wrote correct. And my program doesn't work with win, draw, lose. 
Only with team but really strange result. 
I attach result on the picture in the top and change code, what can be wrong?